# Mysql Вывести первую таблицу и количество записей во второй

Tags: mysql, sql

есть две таблицы. Таблица категорий и таблица статей, хочу вывести категории и показать число статей в категории. Подскажите как сделать вывод таблицы.

Comment: А какой внешний ключ у статей, который их связывает с категориями?

Comment: @Buson - id_cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать групповую функцию `COUNT` с ключевым словом `GROUP BY`

```
select
  к.имя_категории, count(c.статья_ключ)
from категорий к,
     статьи с  
where с.категория_ключ = к.категория_ключ
group by к.имя_категории
```

Или через подзапрос

```
select
  к.*,
  (select 
     count(*)
   from статьи с
   where с.категория_ключ = к.категория_ключ)
from категорий к
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь Alex R , на основе его ответа я решил свою проблему вот таким способом:

```
    public function get_bar(){
    $query = "SELECT
                c.name_catalog, c.cat, count(s.cat) as cat_count
                FROM catalog c,info s
                WHERE c.cat = s.cat
                GROUP BY c.cat";
```

И всё заработало.